# How to handle multiple enums from Binary data type in single match statement in Rust

Tags: rust, match

My main objective is to write the `buy()` function here. The function can receive either `Cars` or `Bike` enum in a Binary format.

Following is my code:

```
use cosmwasm_std::{from_binary, to_binary, Binary};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Cars {
    Audi { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
    Bmw { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Bikes {
    Yamaha { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
    Bajaj { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
}

fn buy(prop: Binary) {
    match from_binary(&prop).unwrap() {
        Cars::Audi { id, number_plate } => {
            println!("{:?}", (id, number_plate));
        }
        _ => {}
    }
    match from_binary(&prop).unwrap() {
        Bikes::Yamaha { id, number_plate } => {
            println!("{:?}", (id, number_plate));
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Cars::Audi {
        id: 0,
        number_plate: 1,
    };
    let y = Bikes::Yamaha {
        id: 0,
        number_plate: 1,
    };

    buy(to_binary(&x).unwrap());
    buy(to_binary(&y).unwrap());
}
```

When I am trying to do it this way, its giving me this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseErr 
{ target_type: "some_testing::Bikes", msg: "unknown variant `Audi`, expected 
`Yamaha` or `Bajaj`" }', src/main.rs:23:30
```

What is the appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: Can you create a wrapper `enum Vehicle { Bike(Bikes), Car(Cars) }` and have `from_binary` return a `Vehicle`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The enums are coming from an external library, so I can't change that. As I said, I am trying to write `buy()` function.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to just merge the two traits to sidestep the issue entirely. However, I'm guessing that may not be an option for you or it would not make much conceptual sense for the types.

The way to resolve your issue is to match `Ok(_)` as well as the enum variable instead of unwrapping. Unwrapping will cause it to panic if it was unable to parse the data to one of your enum variants. You still will need to have two if statements though since the two values being parsed are unrelated types. Here I use `if let` statements instead of `match` statements to make it a little more concise since it only matched a single variant.

```rust
fn buy(prop: Binary) {
    if let Ok(Cars::Audi { id, number_plate }) = from_binary(&prop) {
        println!("{:?}", (id, number_plate));
    }

    if let Ok(Bikes::Yamaha { id, number_plate }) = from_binary(&prop) {
        println!("{:?}", (id, number_plate));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but as you suggested it's not ideal. This will work well for handling 2-3 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would go with serdes `Untagged enum` ([see documentation](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html)). You can see that it works in `buy_json`.
However in this library it fails with `internal error: entered unreachable code`. I've checked the code and found the following statement:

> /// Unsupported. We rely on typed deserialization methods, even if a JSON
> /// has enough type information to detect types in many cases.
> ///
> /// See https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html to learn more about the differentiation
> /// between `deserialize_{type}` and `deserialize_any`.

You can workaround that with something similar to `buy_workaround`.

```
use cosmwasm_std::{from_binary, to_binary, Binary, StdError};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{from_str, to_string};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Cars {
    Audi { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
    Bmw { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Bikes {
    Yamaha { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
    Bajaj { id: u32, number_plate: u32 },
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Wrappy {
    Car(Cars),
    Bike(Bikes),
}

fn buy(prop: Binary) {
    match from_binary::<Wrappy>(&prop) {
        Ok(ok) => match ok {
            Wrappy::Car(car) => match car {
                Cars::Audi { id, number_plate } => println!("Binary Audi {:?}", (id, number_plate)),
                _ => {
                    println!("Other car")
                }
            },
            Wrappy::Bike(bike) => match bike {
                Bikes::Yamaha { id, number_plate } => {
                    println!("Binary Yamaha {:?}", (id, number_plate))
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("Other bike")
                }
            },
        },
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}

fn buy_workaround(prop: Binary) {
    if let Some(ok) = get_wrapper(&prop) {
        match ok {
            Wrappy::Car(car) => match car {
                Cars::Audi { id, number_plate } => println!("Binary Audi {:?}", (id, number_plate)),
                _ => {
                    println!("Other car")
                }
            },
            Wrappy::Bike(bike) => match bike {
                Bikes::Yamaha { id, number_plate } => {
                    println!("Binary Yamaha {:?}", (id, number_plate))
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("Other bike")
                }
            },
        }
    }
}

fn get_wrapper(prop: &Binary) -> Option<Wrappy> {
    match from_binary::<Cars>(prop) {
        Ok(car) => Some(Wrappy::Car(car)),
        Err(StdError::ParseErr { .. }) => match from_binary::<Bikes>(prop) {
            Ok(bike) => Some(Wrappy::Bike(bike)),
            Err(_) => None,
        },
        _ => None,
    }
}

fn buy_json(prop: &str) {
    match from_str::<Wrappy>(prop) {
        Ok(ok) => match ok {
            Wrappy::Car(car) => match car {
                Cars::Audi { id, number_plate } => println!("Json Audi {:?}", (id, number_plate)),
                _ => {
                    println!("Other car")
                }
            },
            Wrappy::Bike(bike) => match bike {
                Bikes::Yamaha { id, number_plate } => {
                    println!("Json Yamaha {:?}", (id, number_plate))
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("Other bike")
                }
            },
        },
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Cars::Audi {
        id: 0,
        number_plate: 1,
    };
    let y = Bikes::Yamaha {
        id: 0,
        number_plate: 1,
    };

    let json = to_string(&x).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);

    buy_json(&json);
    buy_json(&to_string(&y).unwrap());

    println!(
        "Binary format: {:?}",
        String::from_utf8_lossy(to_binary(&x).unwrap().as_slice())
    );

    buy_workaround(to_binary(&x).unwrap());
    buy_workaround(to_binary(&y).unwrap());

    buy(to_binary(&x).unwrap());
    buy(to_binary(&y).unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am only trying to write the `buy()` function properly. I don't like the idea of creating another enum for this.

Comment: @Scruffy How else would the code know what it should try to deserialize to? You've to list the possibilities somewhere.